# How do I fix the system tray icon for Intel Rapid Storage Technology?

Tags: windows-7, raid, intel-rst

I have the Intel Rapid Storage Technology icon enabled:

[image: Intel Rapid Storage Technology window]

But I don't get it in my system tray. I am not in Safe Mode. The problem is when it starts verifying my RAID array and I have no way of knowing! Is there a simple way of fixing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Why not just uninstall and reinstall the utility (might as well get the latest version from Intel while you're at it)?  Uninstalling it isn't going to cause your RAID setup to suddenly vanish or anything.

Comment: I tried reinstalling it, but not uninstalling the UI. I'll try that when I get home.

Comment: Turns out what I thought I was reinstalling was actually the wrong executable (it just extracted the drivers, not install them).  Oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I had to uninstall the Intel Rapid Storage Technology user interface from my computer because it was starting a Verify & Repair after every forced restart of my computer (it's been crashing a LOT).

After that, I knew I needed to get this fixed quick, so I went to the download page:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/55005/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-

And I needed to find out the current version of my RAID driver, so I went to Administrative Tools / Device Manager / Disk drives / Right-clicked my RAID array / Properties / Driver tab / Driver Details / Click C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\iaStorF.sys.

That let me know that I had version 13.2.4.1000. I downloaded the setup for that  version and reinstalled it. This did not fix the system tray icon. **However**, I decided to reinstall again, and selected "Repairs errors in the most recent installation by fixing missing and corrupt files, shortcuts, and registry entries."

That finally fixed it and I have the system tray icon back.